# I can't extend a class to another class who has constructor

Tags: java

In inheritance we have learnt that to access another class's methods we should   write "extends(the parent class)". Well, it is **strong text** working. But I have created a class 'People' which has constructor 'People' in it. I created another class 'Player'. whenever i am trying to extend the 'Player' class to 'People' class  error is showing (saying..."Constructor Player is undefined")

[image: Error message]

. How can I manage this problem?

Comment: Yes, so you need to declare a constructor in `Player` that delegates to the `People` constructor using `super(...)`. It's not clear how you're learning Java, but there should be a complete section in whatever book/tutorial you're using about constructors - you want the section that's about chaining to another constructor.

Comment: Have you [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)?

Comment: _Constructor Player is undefined_ but did you tried to defined it ? Eclipse propose you to generate it for you (see the icon on the left of that line)

Comment: thank you all, its really helpful

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code in questions. Copy/paste the code itself - it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a Constructor in Player Class that have the needed parameters like this

```
public Player(String x,int y,String d){}
```

because you are not working with an empty constructor of the class Player 
or you can do this

```
Player player = new People("",some int value,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no similar parameter constructor defined in your child class. There are 2 ways you can resolve this.

1. If you want to create object and initialize parameter with constructor.
   Create constructor in Player class.

   ```
   public Player(String name, String age, String hairColor) {
    super(a);
   }
   ```

use this constructor to create object as you have done in your main method.

2. If You don't want to create object using parameterized constructor but instead you want to use setter methods.
   Define a default constructor in parent(People) class, so that you don't need to create any constructor in child class.

If you create any constructor in a class(in your case People), compiler doesn't create default constructor(No parameter constructor), further you have not created any constructor in Player class, so, compiler creates default constructor in your Player class,

```
    Public Player(){
    super();
    }
```

but there is no default constructor in People, so call to `super();` will throw compilation error, that is the reason it becomes mandatory to create parameterized constructor. So, just create a default constructor in People class and use setter methods:

```
    public People(){

    }
```